# HP ALM Synchronizer TFS 2010 mapping workitem

Tags: alm

What does this error means...??

EndpointParams: Endpoint params check failed. Reason: Folder Work Item verification failed. Verify that the folder work item, name field and description field are configured correctly in the adapter's dat folder.

Any idea..

Answer (score 0):

In HP ALM Synchronizer, in the Advanced tab of the configuration of the link you should be able to set endpoint params. Check that you have set a value for all params.
Refer to page 75 of [HP ALM Synchronizer User Guide](http://update.external.hp.com/qualitycenter/qc110/sync/almsynchronizer/HP-ALM-Sync-UserGuide.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for using HP ALM Synchronizer.
To work with TFS and ALM at requirement sync, sometimes you want copy the hierarchy structure to another endpoint. So we provided folder sync on TFS adapter.

To use this feature, we need understand we will recognize a work item in TFS as folders in ALM. For example, you can make work item "Group" as folders.

Edit **HP ALM Synchronizer\adapters\dat\TFS\adapter.properties**
Uncomment folder items, specify which work time you want to map to folder:
tfs.adapter.folder.work.item=Group

Specify which attribute of this work item you want to map to ALM folder name and description:
**tfs.adapter.folder.field.name=Title**

**tfs.adapter.folder.field.description=Description**

And restart the service.

Then we also need put all requirements you want to sync under "Group" in TFS (by using linking function in TFS).

Finally your groups in TFS will become folder in ALM and all sub items will keep the hierarchy structure in ALM.

Hope this helpful.

Comment: Hi，Geroge. Could you help to look at this question ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38864630/how-to-enable-folder-level-synchronization-between-hp-alm-to-microsoft-team-foun