# How to enable folder level Synchronization between HP ALM to Microsoft Team Foundation Server,using HP ALM Synchronizer client 12.53

Tags: tfs, synchronization, manual-testing, hp-alm

1. Synchronize HP ALM to TFS
2. Used HP ALM Synchronizer client
3. How to edit the **adapter.properties** file in ALM to synchronize two       folders
   4.Want to synchronize two folders(synchronized folder) should be reflected in both the apllications

Comment: Did you mean the method mentioned  by @George - HPE RnD in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16155724/hp-alm-synchronizer-tfs-2010-mapping-workitem/38841229#38841229 ？

Answer (score 1):

thanks for using Synchronizer.
Your question is not detail enough.
adapter.properties file can do several things like:

1. Define folder sync for TFS.
2. Define work item subtype hierarchy structure.

You can find details in user guide, or you can ask more specific questions.